# Should I free strdup pointer after basename/dirname in C?

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc, strdup

I want to use POSIX's `basename` function (as opposed to GNU's).

From the man page:

> Both  dirname()  and  basename() may modify the contents of path, so
>   it may be desirable to pass a copy when calling one of these functions.
>
> These functions may return pointers to statically allocated memory which may be overwritten by subsequent calls.   **Alternatively,
>   they  may return a pointer to some part of path**, so that the string referred to by path should not be modified or freed until the
>   pointer returned by the function is no longer required.

It also says:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>          Both dirname() and basename() return pointers to null-terminated strings.  (**Do not pass these pointers to free**(3).)

So the example suggests something like:

> **EXAMPLE**
>
> ```
>        char *dirc, *basec, *bname, *dname;
>        char *path = "/etc/passwd";
>
>        dirc = strdup(path);
>        basec = strdup(path);
>        dname = dirname(dirc);
>        bname = basename(basec);
>        printf("dirname=%s, basename=%s\n", dname, bname);
> ```

The `strdup`(`strndup`) man page says:

> Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

So the question is: Should I free dirc and basec (as per `strdup`) or not (as per `basename`)?

Comment: You free dirc and basec (as per strdup) and you don't free dname and bname (as per basename/dirname). But you can't free dirc until you don't need dname anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dname` and `bname` could be using parts of `dirc` and `basec` respectively, so it's not safe to free `dirc` or `basec`.

I'd do an `strdup` of the results from the `dirname` and `basename` calls. Then it is safe to free`dirc` and `basec`, and you KNOW you have to free your copies.

(yes it's messy, but I think it's cleaner than remembering you can't free `dirc` yet because `dname` may or may not be using it...)